# Featured image using rmd in hugo-academic

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

How can I create a image preview for a post in hugo-academic when using R Markdown？TOML uses the following syntax:

```
[image]
  # Caption (optional)
  caption = ""

  # Focal point (optional)
  # Options: Smart, Center, TopLeft, Top, TopRight, Left, Right, BottomLeft, Bottom, BottomRight
  focal_point = ""
```

However, if I use this in the rmd, it doesn't work.

```
---
image:
    caption:''
    focal_point:''
---
```

Answer (score 0):

The post shared by [declast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53287931/9882732) is very useful. Specifically for me, I changed the name of my Rmd file to index.Rmd, then everything worked.